# Can't use variable inside @using{}

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a `foreach` and inside it I have a `using`:

```
@foreach (var solution in solutions){
   //some code
   @solution.Id
   @using(Html.BeginForm("somemodel", "Admin", new { @viewName = "viewname" }, FormMethod.Post)){
     @solution.Id
   }
}
```

The problem is that `solution.Id` has for example value `4` outside and inside the `using` it is always 1.

[image]

The button outside represents the value solution.Id have, the 1 inside the form is the value solution.Id have insiede the using

Can someone explain to me why?

Comment: There's not enough information here to let us figure out why the value changes on you. Can you read [ask] and make a [mre]?

Comment: @gunr2171 is all there, in the foreach there is this using that is used to store some data but isen't the problem, the problem is that the value of solution.id is allways 1 inside in using and changes in the foreach as normal

Comment: No there isn't. "somecode" inside the using signature can (and must) hide the reasonfor the value change.

Comment: Also, are you 100% certain your backend is setting these ID's properly? You post a snippet from the front end, but if the `some code` block isn't setting that ID to something else, then this issue may be on the backend. Make some unit tests to be sure, or include the suspect code block from backend

Comment: I've edited it, there is no bug in the backend, solution.id is 4 after 4 cycles, inside using is allways 1

Comment: My guess is that somehow this code is converted to a lambda capturing the first value of `@solution.Id`. Try to assign it to a local `var id = solution.Id;` and use `id` instead.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I've tried already, inside and outside, nothing changed, tried to debug it and the value changes in the debug but once displyed it's 1.